# Why does my code not output anything in the terminal. Starts a new line no errors

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, clang++

This is my code in the C++ file:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is Clang. Yes I do put "clang++" in the terminal. The problem is, is that it runs it and doesn't output anything. It just starts a new line.
I am running Clang version 3.8.0.

Answer (score 2):

As you said clang++ is the compiler, that is, it turns your code into a binary file that can be executed. It doesn't execute the program itself.

By default the compiled file name is `a.out`, so after compiling, to execute the program you should run:

```
./a.out
```

---

You could specify the output file name like so:

```
clang++ infile.cpp -o outfile
```

and then run the binary:

```
./outfile
```